# tomcat jdbc connection pooling with Oracle database

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

We are using tomcat jdbc connection pooling with Oracle database. 
Recently, we encountered problem that there are too many inactive session in Oracle database from JDBC THIN CLIENT.

Can anyone help us in this? Why is it causing inactive session in the database and what can be the solution to this.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is it a 'problem' that you have inactive sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust settings of your pool, following [the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html). Setting `maxIdle` and `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` to low values would ensure that idle connections are evicted fast, and that few idle connections stay open. Obviously, it will also make your pool less efficient, since connections will be closed and opened more frequently.

Comment: `maxActive` should changed to avoid the too many sessions problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `SQLException`s because connections have timed out, you should set a `validationQuery` (to something like `SELECT 0 FROM DUAL`) and your connections will be tested before they are checked-out of the pool. Any connection that has failed will be replaced by a working connection and then returned to your code.